# Generating a dictionary from two lists

Tags: python

I have a requirement to convert two list into a dictionary. Just wondering if there is an easiet and pythonic way of doing it.

i can acheive that using the code below but wanted to know if this is the right way of doing it

```
a = ['1.1.1.1','1.1.1.2']
b = ['225.1.1.1','225.1.1.2']
d = {}
for i,j in enumerate(a):
    d[j]= b[i]

print(d)
```

Comment: It looks like you're pairing IPv4 addresses. Are you sure lists will always be the same length? can a single key (from `a` list) be paired with differents values (from `b` list) or viceversa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip),

```
a = ['1.1.1.1','1.1.1.2']
b = ['225.1.1.1','225.1.1.2']
dict(zip(a,b))
```